# Export php to csv

Tags: php, export-to-csv

I would like to ask if it is possible that before exporting php data to csv it would be query first or filtered(ex: searching a name)? I have a code in exporting php data to csv but I would like it to be filtered first.

This is my code of exporting php data to csv.

```
<?php

// call export function
exportMysqlToCsv('export_csv.csv');


// export csv
function exportMysqlToCsv($filename = 'export_csv.csv')
{

   $conn = dbConnection();
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$sql_query = "SELECT id, name, code FROM toy";

// Gets the data from the database
$result = $conn->query($sql_query);

$f = fopen('php://temp', 'wt');
$first = true;
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($first) {
        fputcsv($f, array_keys($row));
        $first = false;
    }
    fputcsv($f, $row);
} // end while

$conn->close();

$size = ftell($f);
rewind($f);

header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Length: $size");
// Output to browser with appropriate mime type, you choose ;)
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-type: text/csv");
header("Content-type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
fpassthru($f);
exit;

}

// db connection function
function dbConnection(){
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "louchin";
$dbname = "phppot_examples";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
return $conn;
}

?>
```

Please help me and suggest if possible. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The data is called up in the SQL query:

`$sql_query = "SELECT id, name, code FROM toy";`

I think you can just add a `WHERE` clause to this to add your filters.

A quick Google for 'MySQL WHERE' will give you plenty of places you can look up the syntax.

Comment: Yes I know that! But I would to search it first. Please do comment first to clarify. Thanks

Comment: I would like to query it first; ex: I would like to search for a toy car and all named "toy car" would show. I can query it first but I don't know how to export to csv. In the above code it is directly exported to csv.